# JavaFX и OpenGL

Tags: javafx, opengl, jogl

Есть ли возможность использовать OpenGL (JOGL) в JavaFX? Для Swing примеров полно, а вот для JavaFX не удается найти.

Хотелось бы понять, как использовать OpenGL в JavaFX (например, вывести изображения примитивов на экран)

Comment: Допустим "есть" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946030). Этого ответа достаточно? Попробуйте уточнить вопрос, что именно вам нужно?

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, как использовать OpenGL в JavaFX (как вывести изображения примитивов на экран?)

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно найти пример или туториал. Такие вопросы не совсем в рамках данного сайта.

Comment: C этим и возникают проблемы. Для swing примеров полно, а вот для javafx не удается найти.